# About Homological Mirror Symmetry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics, mirror-symmetry

Why in homological mirror symmetry, we restrict us to a projective variety (Calabi-Yau manifold)? Because in physics we don't need this condition.

What's the general picture for general Calabi-Yau manifold?

Comment: I think that this is much more likely to get answers if posted on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Yau gives some quick explanation of this in his [scholaropedia page for CY manifolds](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Calabi-Yau_manifold#Calabi-Yau_Manifolds_in_Physics) (which is really a great read if you're interested in such things).  In particular, speaking about spacetime manifolds $\mathbb{R}^{3,1}\times X$  (with standard Minkowski metric on the first part), he says "for the most basic product models $N=1$ supersymmetry, the space $X$ must be a Calabi-Yau manifold of complex dimension $3$".

He references a 1985 paper of Candelas, Horowitz, Strominger and Witten.